# How can i add single Manufacturer products to cart per Order- Opencart 2.0.3.1

Tags: php, opencart2.x

I'm using Opencart 2.0.3.1. I have two Manufacturers.Each has two products. I should be able to add two products from the first manufacturer in to the Shopping cart and when i try to add product from the second manufacturer it should not allow to add.

It should tell the customer to order it separately.

I was able to achieve to add single item to cart using clear function. But it will be more sense if we are able to achieve single Manufacturer products per order.

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify the add method in the *ControllerCheckoutCart*.
So open the file **/catalog/controller/checkout/cart.php** and find the following line

```
public function add()
```

In this function approx at line 336 replce this two lines with

```
            $this->cart->add($this->request->post['product_id'], $quantity, $option, $recurring_id);

            $json['success'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_success'), $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $this->request->post['product_id']), $product_info['name'], $this->url->link('checkout/cart'));
```

these lines

```
            //BEGIN OF THE PATCH
            /*
            OTRIGINAL CODE
            $this->cart->add($this->request->post['product_id'], $quantity, $option, $recurring_id);

            $json['success'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_success'), $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $this->request->post['product_id']), $product_info['name'], $this->url->link('checkout/cart'));
            */
            //control if the cart isn't empty
            $can_add_product=true;
            if ($this->cart->hasProducts()>0){
                $products = $this->cart->getProducts();
                foreach ($products as $product) {
                    $product_just_in_cart = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product['product_id']);
                    $manufacturer_id_in_cart=$product_just_in_cart['manufacturer_id'];
                    $manufacturer_name_in_cart=$product_just_in_cart['manufacturer'];
                    //we just analyze only the first product
                    break;
                }    

                if ($product_info['manufacturer_id']!=$manufacturer_id_in_cart) {
                    $can_add_product=false;
                }
            }

            if ($can_add_product) { 
                $this->cart->add($this->request->post['product_id'], $quantity, $option, $recurring_id);

                $json['success'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_success'), $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $this->request->post['product_id']), $product_info['name'], $this->url->link('checkout/cart'));
            }
            else {
                $json['success'] =sprintf('For this order you can add only products of '.$manufacturer_name_in_cart, $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $this->request->post['product_id']), $product_info['name'], $this->url->link('checkout/cart'));

            }
            //END OF THE PATCH
```

You can test this patch [here](http://customize_my_opencart_2_0_3_1.nablacom.it/)

Comment: I have tested this, even if i add another products from the same manufacturer, it throws the same message "For this order you can add only products of" also it is created undefined in Shopping card preview see this snapshot http://prnt.sc/cir99c

Comment: I'm using the last version of OpenCart. Please share a print_r of $products[0]

Comment: Ok . I'm using version 2.0.3.1. I will share the print_r i

Comment: It's printing NULL value, I could see empty space

Comment: I installed OpenCart 2.0.3.1 and I modifed the patch. It works and the correct solution is published as update of the original answer

Comment: Thank you Roberto ! Works like a charm

Comment: Hi Robert, Can you please let me know the changes you have done for OC 2.3.0.2 when you initially posted